# App crashing when adding onclicklistener

Tags: android

I'm kind of new to android programming.
I am having a lot of trouble with adding Onclicklistener to a button.
When I remove that part, the app runs fine.
When I add it, the app crashes immediately.
Here is my Main Activity code:

```
 public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button pwrecovery;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text ="hello toast!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set up notitle
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //set up full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    pwrecovery=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pwrecovery);
        pwrecovery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have any idea why it does that?

Thanks in advance guys.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#02496b"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/quote_eng"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
         />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:fontFamily=""
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sign_in"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/button_signin4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_fd"
        android:background="@drawable/button_fblogin_small2"
        android:text="@string/logfb"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_fb"
        android:background="@drawable/button_glogin_small"
        android:text="@string/logg"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    >




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pwrecovery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lost_password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>
   </RelativeLayout>




     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat from the crash? Look for a line starting `E/` and containing the phrase `Caused By`. My guess is that `findViewById()` is failing to find `R.id.pwrecovery`.

Comment: Can you show your activity_login.xml?

Comment: why you set `Context context = getApplicationContext();`.Not good approach . remove  `getApplicationContext()` and oncreate section declare `context = getApplicationContext()` and make sure your ID .show xml

Comment: I believed your button pwrecovery is null and have different id in activity_login layout

Comment: Check whether you've declared the button name from your layout file correctly. It'd be something like `android:id="@+id/yourButtonName"`

Comment: Please share error logcat

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys, I added the XML.
I tried adding LogCat but I can't find any line with 'caused by', I did a search with ctrl + f. Also, Thanks for the help Amiya but it did not fix it.

Comment: Use String instead of CharSequence in Toast

Comment: Just replace CharSequence to String

Answer (score 1):

Please use fully qualified activity object instead of context.

```
    pwrecovery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity .this, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as you are unable to post logcat

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button pwrecovery;
    Context context;
    Stringtext ="hello toast!";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set up notitle
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //set up full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        context = this;
        pwrecovery=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pwrecovery);
        pwrecovery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! So the problem was in my declarations at start?

Comment: Seems you've not declared `context` properly.

Comment: I don't really know how :S

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can also use the Toast like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Your Code & Passkey", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just change from

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
```

To

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You called an instance method before the instance was fully created, and you have stored that as a member variable

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

Activities **are** Context objects. That variable is not necessary, and should be replaced by `LoginActivity.this`